Multiplexer with inverter and transmission gate

I'm currently studying the multiplexer shown in the figure. Since adding inverters does not affect the overall output of the circuit, what is the significance of adding the three inverters (inv1, inv2 and inv3)? Do these inverters help improve the overall performance of the circuit?

Hint: how would you implement a CMOS buffer on the transistor level?

"So this design is just used as a buffer before the input signal and after the output signal?"
